# how do char pointers work with while loop

Tags: c, pointers, char

In the while loop when `*s` is mentioned it means the value at the address contained in `s`, so in the first case, the value will be 'a',

my question is how will while loop checks it, does it checks the ASCII value of the characters to check the condition is true or false ..are some other way?

```
main()
{
   char str[] = "abcd" ;
   char *s = str;
   while(*s)
       printf ("%c",*s++) ;
}
```

Comment: A non-zero value means True. Value of a `char` is basically an integer. The value of a nul character denoting end of string (`\0`) is zero. The loop stops then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a string variable like

```
char str[] = "abcd";
```

it's like declaring `str[5] = "abcd\0";`

So, in your while loop, it first checks the value of `*s`, which is 'a', that translates to 97 on the ascii table. Then you print the current value inside the *s pointer, and then increase the pointer by 1, which leads to the next character. When you reach the `\0`, the loop exits, because `\0` is equal to 0;

Comment: do you mean that the *s will be converted to 97 in case of a and then evaluated ? so in that case what will happen if my string contains digit 0 will it check for 0 or its ascii 48?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.
If your code contains something like
`char str[] = "abc0123"; `  then every number will also be converted to their respective ASCII values, and then evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

`while(conditon)` in C/C++ code will execute if `condition != 0`

Since it is a dereferenced char*, this means it is a 1 byte value. Which ranges from 0-255.

Since the first value is 'a' this means it will print this table from values 'a'(61) to 'nbsp' (255) after 255 the char value will overflow to '0' or NULL character at which point the `while(condition)` will evaluate to false and the program will end.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. The code doesn't increment the value of *s, just the value of s. So, instead of "going from 61 to 255", it just prints the string, and then ends. Also, that ascii table is outdated. Here's a link to a more updated version: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/ASCII-Table.svg